# Finding the minimized absolute difference of shortest paths of two different starting vertices

Tags: algorithms, graphs

I am relatively new to algorithms and I hoped you can help me with the following question. The question can be summarized as follows:

> Given two different starting vertices, A and B, and a destination vertex, C. Find the shortest path from A -> C and B -> C (assuming there is no negative edges). The graph can be modeled as undirected connected weighted graph. We must satisfy 2 conditions:

1. The sum of the total distance of the shortest path is the smallest
2. The absolute difference between the distance traveled by from each vertex is minimized

Here are my thoughts to solve the question.

Treat this as a All Pair Short Path problem and use Floyd Warshall algorithm. And this will give us the shortest path from A -> C and B -> C.

The issue I have is on how to minimize the absolute difference as I am unable to come up with a solution to this. Am I on the right track to think that I should be using the k-th shortest path algorithm to solve the second condition?

Comment: Do you want to optimize 1 first and then break ties in favor of 2? Could you give an example where condition $2$ is not trivial? I'm not sure I understand it. To satisfy $1$ you need to select a **shortest** path from $A$ to $C$ and a **shortest** path from $B$ to $C$. But then the distance $d(A,C)$ from $A$ to $C$ is independent of **which** shortest path you choose (and so is $d(B,C)$). Therefore the absolute difference is always $|d(A,C) - d(B,C)|$ regardless of the chosen shortest paths.

Comment: The question did mention that the first condition has higher priority then the second. I was having similar doubt because I believe that the distance A to C and distance B to C are independent of each other.